# jQuery call user defined function on load

Tags: jquery, function, undefined, onload

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.fn.newQsNum = function(){
    var num_of_qs = 5;
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*num_of_qs)+1
}

});

$(window).load(newQsNum);
```

how do you call a user defined function on windows load?
when i looked at the error console, it says the newQsNum is undefined.
have i done anything wrong? i just followed

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-add-your-own-custom-functions-to.html

Comment: What exactly you're trying to do here? Your custom function will only be added when the DOM is ready, but before that, you're already trying to assign it (the `load` assignment will run before the stuff in `ready`). You could access your function by `$.fn.newQsNum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call your function with `newQsNum()` because you added it to `$.fn`. Also you can call it directly within your document ready wrapper.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.fn.newQsNum = function(){
        var num_of_qs = 5;
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*num_of_qs)+1
    }

    $.fn.newQsNum();

});
```

Comment: i love you :D thanks xD the blog told me to call it only by its function name. never thought that i need to add '$.fn' thanks

Answer (score 0):

call it inside doc ready-

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$.fn.newQsNum(); 

});
```